# Language detection using deepl's python library

Tags: python, deepl

Is there a way to use the deepl [Python client library](https://pypi.org/project/deepl/) (or raw [API](https://www.deepl.com/pro-api?cta=header-pro-api/)) to detect the source language (without translating it)? The marketing blurb on the [API website](https://www.deepl.com/pro-api) says, detection is available but I can't find it anywhere in the library or API.

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more about what you're trying to achieve and maybe I can help you :)

Comment: I'm thinking about a solution for mastodon. Currently people have to manually label their toots (posts) with a language, but many don't. I was thinking if one could use deepl for language detection since mastodon is already using deepl for translation.

Comment: Thats an interesting idea, while the API currently does not have that functionality I can totally see how it could be useful, let me ask the devs about this.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, our API does not support "just" detecting the language. Our recommendation would be to try translating a small part of the sentence and use the detected language from the response.

Even if we had a separate /detectLanguage endpoint, using it would be similar to this approach as you had to send some text anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I worked quite some time with deepl due to its simplicity, to be honest, I don't think deepl has that feature as a standalone function. But if you send a request to translate you will get the detected language in the response. If you have the starter package you can translate unlimited texts, so this might be a viable workaround.

If you are open to another tool, LibreTranslate has a detect endpoint but the pricing is a bit more expensive. However, you can host it yourself if you have the infrastructure for it.
https://libretranslate.com/docs/